# Diferenças e uso de Strings vs. CharSequence

Tags: java, android, string, tipagem

Muitos métodos no Java esperam parâmetros `CharSequence`, porem o código roda normalmente quando eu passo uma `String` sem conversão, por exemplo:

```java
String mensagem = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.MENSAGEM);

TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.minha_text_view);

// O Método setText requer o parâmetro do tipo CharSequence, então:
t.setText((CharSequence) mensagem);

// Porem posso usar sem conversão
t.setText(mensagem);
```

Qual a diferença entre os tipos e por quê não ocorre um erro quando o tipo não esperado é passado como parâmetro?
Existe algum ponto negativo em não converter a `String` para `CharSequence`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) é uma interface do Java que representa uma sequência de caracteres.

A classe [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) implementa essa interface e permite usar *polimorfismo* em métodos que recebem `CharSequence` como parâmetro, isto é, receber uma implementação específica, mas tratar o parâmetro através de um tipo mais genérico.

A própria classe `String` utiliza parâmetros `CharSequence` em vários métodos, por exemplo o [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). Isso permite a interoperabilidade com outras classes de representação de texto que também implementam a interface `CharSequence`, tal como o [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: Excelente, imaginei algo do tipo, mas preferi posta a dúvida e aprender da forma correta.

Answer (score 6):

A razão da existência do `CharSequence` é que muitas vezes é interessante dar mais flexibilidade nos parâmetros a serem aceitos por uma função. Isso evita conversões desnecessárias - e muitas vezes custosas - permitindo um código mais genérico e eficiente.

Por exemplo, se seu algoritmo precisa de um **conjunto** de objetos, por que exigir que a entrada seja um `ArrayList`? Aceita `Collection`, afinal `ArrayList` implementa a interface `Collection` (e muitas outras classes também). Agora, se ele precisa de uma **lista ordenada** de elementos, é melhor pedir como parâmetro um `List` (ainda dando escolha entre `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` e outros). E assim por diante...

Strings em Java são imutáveis. Por isso, se você está no meio de uma operação que manipula strings (usando o `StringBuilder`, `CharBuffer` ou outra coisa do tipo) e precisa passar essa string para um outro método, seria ineficiente primeiro converter numa `String` (o que implica na cópia de todo o seu conteúdo) para depois passar como argumento. O que o método precisa é de uma "sequência ordenada de caracteres", então o ideal é aceitar qualquer classe que implementa esses requisitos.

E sobre por que Java aceita `String` no lugar de `CharSequence`, isso está respondido por @utluiz: porque `CharSequence` é uma interface, que `String` implementa. Como [na herança] sempre é possível usar um tipo mais específico no lugar de um tipo mais genérico, uma conversão não é necessária.

Comment: muito bom, sua resposta também adicionou muito a pergunta.

Comment: Cara, isso que você falou, pelo menos na minha concepção é relativo. Em alguns casos é importante sim generalizar a implementação, mas deixar um código mais genérico, **na maioria das vezes**, torna o código menos eficiente, já que o computador (ou a VM, no caso do Java) tem que tratar essa generalização especificando cada elemento.
Mas, em geral, a generalização paga o seu custo computacional. (:

Comment: @felipe.avelar Concordo. Tomando a própria `List` como exemplo, ordenar um `ArrayList` é muito mais eficiente que ordenar um `LinkedList` (tanto é que o Java o converte num array antes de fazê-lo). Os detalhes de implementação, longe de serem irrelevantes, podem ser "explorados" para aumentar a eficiência do código. Só é preciso ter cuidado para não "perder a floresta pelas árvores": uma maior eficiência **local** vale pouco se comprometer a eficiência **global**. "Conversão ineficiente -> cálculo eficiente -> conversão ineficiente" pode ser pior que "cálculo ineficiente".