# Como atribuir retorno de textview a uma string?

Tags: java, android

Bom sou iniciante em Android/Java, queria fazer o seguinte pegar o resultado de um textview que é pego através do barcode scan e jogar numa string para fazer uma lista de resultados pegos pelo barcode scan. Como faço para jogar o resultado em uma string?

Segue o trecho do código:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

txResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txResult);

String[] itens = new String[]{"Item 1", "Item 2"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,(itens));
```

Deste modo mosta na tela o Listview com o item 1 e 2, quero que seja mostrado com o retorno do txResult.

Obrigado.

Comment: Vitor, você não precisa usar a tag `android-studio` quando o seu problema não estiver relacionado à IDE. Veja [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246) pergunta

Comment: ok, valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o [`getText()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()) desta forma:

```
String texto = txResult.getText().toString();
```

Como o `getText()` retorna um `CharSequence`, é necessário fazer o Cast para evitar erro de tipo, pois uma [`String` é um `charsequence`, mas nem sempre o contrário é verdadeiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2114/diferen%C3%A7as-e-uso-de-strings-vs-charsequence).