# Como criar um vetor em cujos indices fossem caracteres de uma string informada?

Tags: java, array, string

Queria criar um vetor em java em que cada indice do vetor fosse um caracter de uma string que eu informasse

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    String[] words = {"java"};

    System.out.println("\n"+words[3]);  //para dar um print na letra"a"

}
```

Comment: Poderia formatar adequadamente seu código? Basta selecionar ele e teclar `ctrl + k`

Comment: Ok , eu só queria fazer esse vetor receber uma string e eu poder separar cada carácter dele em um índice do vetor, não sei se ficou claro

Answer (score 5):

Não precisa transformar em array, basta chamar o método [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) passando o posição da letra, pois [**toda String é um CharSequence**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2114/28595), ou seja, uma sequencia de caracteres que podem ser capturados utilizando o método citado.

```
String word = "java";

System.out.println("\n"+ word.charAt(3));
```

Veja funcionando no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ms1Hex).

> Obs.: é sempre bom verificar se o indice passado é menor que o tamanho da string através da verificação `seuIndice < palavra.length` pois se o indice passado para este método for maior que o tamanho da string, será lançada uma exceção `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Lembrando que o indice de uma palavra começa de 0 até o tamanho da String -1.

Mas se mesmo com toda essa facilidade fornecida pela linguagem você quiser insistir em criar array, também é possivel converter uma String em um array de `char`, com o método `toCharArray()`:

```
char[] words = "java".toCharArray();
System.out.println("\n"+words[3]);
```

Veja também em funcionamento no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/HBHzi9).

Answer (score 3):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * Vamos utilizar para ler as informações do console...
         */
        BufferedReader buffReader = null;
        try {
            /**
             * Criamos uma instancia do fluxo de entrada padrão. Esse fluxo já está aberto e
             * pronto para fornecer dados de entrada. Este fluxo corresponde à entrada do
             * teclado (normalmente) do usuário.
             */
            buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            while (true) { // irá permanecer nesta iteração, até que o usuário digite sair!

                // pedimos ao usuário uma palavra
                System.out.print("\nDigite\n: ");

                /**
                 * Aguarda o usuário digitar, e quando aperta ENTER, a String input recebe as
                 * informações. Sem incluir nenhum caractere de terminação de linha, ou nulo se
                 * o final do fluxo foi atingido.
                 */
                final String input = buffReader.readLine();

                // compara as String´s ignorando Maisculas e minusculas!
                if ("sair".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) { 
                    System.out.println("Você saiu da aplicação!");
                    // Sai da aplicação
                    System.exit(0); 
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("Você digitou %d letras\n", input.length());
                    // Vamos iterar os carateres!!!
                    final char[] caracteres = input.toCharArray(); 
                    for(int i =0; i < caracteres.length; i++) {
                        System.out.printf("Posição: %d, caracter: %c\n", i, caracteres[i]);
                    }

                }

            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (buffReader != null) {
                try {
                    buffReader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```